# Analytics Ecommerce:addItem with price to zero

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, analytics

We are configuring our analytics account with ecommerce datas, but it seems that we have an issue.

When a client is making a transaction, we iterate through all items in the cart and add them to analytics with **addItem** function but we noticed that when the price of an item is equal to zero, it is not collected in Analytics and so we can't have analytics on it.

Is it normal that this product is not showing on analytics ? 
Do we have to force a price to 0.01 for example ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you set it to 0 or 0.00?

Comment: Hi , i've set it to 0.00

Comment: Can you add the piece of code you're using to iterate and call on the "addItem" function?

Comment: Here is my code :
```ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
                'id': '[CurrentReservation.ID]',  // Order ID. Required
                'name': etab_name.replace("'",""),  // Product Name. Required
                'sku': '[Product.ProductCode]',  // SKU (identifiant produit)
                'price': '[Product.TotalAmount format="0.00;;."]', // Price
                'quantity': '[Product.Quantity.Value]'  // Quantity
            });```